# Allow CI access to private BitBucket repo

Tags: ssh, continuous-integration, bitbucket, fastlane, visual-studio-app-center

I'm running a CI machine on AppCenter and need to allow read/write access to a private BitBucket repository but I can't figure out how to do this.

My approach is to create an ssh key and during CI builds add the private key to the machine `ssh-agent` using `ssh-add -K` (mac machine).

I've created an `ssh` key on my local computer (mac) using `ssh-keygen` and uploaded the `.pub` key to BitBucket. Then as my CI runs I'm trying to take the **private key** and add it to the `ssh-agent` but I'm being prompt to enter a password and can't figure out how to inject it in a non-interactive shell mode.

**Is this the right approach to grant access to BitBucket in CI? if so, how can I add an ssh key without being prompt to enter a password?**

- Scripts are in Ruby or Bash.
- The repo contains certificates used for `Fastlane Match`

Answer (score 7):

Answering my own question...

I ended up using `BitBucket AppPasword` and cloning via `https`. I think there has to be a better way but this work for my needs at the moment.

I needed access from my CI to a private BitBucket certificates repo to use with `Fastlane Match`, the value in my **MatchFile** for`git_url` that allows me to clone the repo is:

```
git_url "https://{BITBUCKET_USER}:{BITBUCKET_APP_PASSWORD}@bitbucket.org/{BITBUCKET_USER}/{REPO}.git"
```

You can obtain a bitbucket app password by clicking your profile (Avatar) -> Settings -> App Passwords